# How to skip mongoose pre-save hook?

Tags: save, hook, mongoose, middleware, pre

I have a book model. Here's its schema

```
BookSchema = new Schema({
    title: String
    , lowestPrice: Number
});
BookSchema.path('title').required(true);
Bookchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    try {
        // chai.js
        expect(this.title).to.have.length.within(1, 50);
    } catch (e) {
        next(e);
    }
    next();
});
```

When a goods of a book is created, I have to update the book's lowest price if the goods' price is lower than the origin one. For I need to know the origin lowest price, I can't use `Book.update()`, which skips the pre-save hook, but use `Book.findById(id).select('lowestPrice')` to find the book than update it. The problem was that I didn't want to select the `title` field, thus when it came to the pre-save hook, a `TypeError` occured for `this.title` was undefined. Are there ways to skip the pre-save hook?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Book.update` with a condition that will only select the document if the new price is lower than the original:

```js
Book.update({_id: id, lowestPrice: {$gt: price}}, {$set: {lowestPrice: price}},
    function (err, numberAffected) {
        if (numberAffected > 0) {
            // lowestPrice was updated.
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that I also want to update other fields of the book whatever the price of the new goods is, not just `lowestPrice`. Also the `lowestPrice` filed is actually an array which keeps track to the lowest prices, so whenever the goods with lowest price is sold, I can update the `lowestPrice` to the second lowest one.

Comment: OK. I don't see a way to skip the save middleware, so you either need to include `'title'` in your select list or figure out a way to do this with `update`.